# Ionic segments inside ionic tab not displaying child page properly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-tabs

I'm using Ionic Tabs layout for my ionic3 application. Inside 1st tabpage, i have 2 ionic-segments (both of them have their own pages.).
Issue is when i click 1st Ionic-tab it then 2 segments are displayed properly but Page content of any of segments are not displaying.
For detailed information, please visit below question link i've posted to ionic forum.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-segment-inside-ionic-tab-not-displaying-child-page-properly/176151

Answer (score 0):

I just converted my Page into Component and it's working as expected now.